Prevent pdoc from leaking environment variables of pydantic-settings
I use pydantic-settings to collect configuration parameters from a variety of sources (config.yaml, .env, environment variables, ...). The settings object is stored as a module variable in a similar fashion to how it is shown for FastAPI here:
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    app_name: str = "Awesome API"
    admin_email: str
    items_per_user: int = 50


settings = Settings()

The only difference is that the label is capitalised and is imported by other modules (from my_app.config import SETTINGS). This works quite well. However, when I use pdoc to generate documentation it will use __repr__/__str__ to document the value of SETTINGS:
SETTINGS: Settings = 
Settings(api=APIConfig(token=SecretStr('**********'), endpoint=SecretStr('**********')), logging=LoggingConfig(level=<LogLevel.DEBUG: 'debug'>), uid=501, device_info=None)

This leaks environment information and in the worst case even credentials, urls or session tokens that have been typed with str instead of SecretStr. I don't want to override __repr__ as it might be useful to log settings during runtime. However, for documentation purposes SETTINGS: Settings without a value should be sufficient as the actual value depends on the user's environment. SETTINGS should be documented though, so readers know it exists and can be accessed.
Is there a way to tell pdoc or pydantic(-settings) to not document the module variable's value? Or is there a better pattern to load and share settings across modules?

have you tried excluding the module with pdoc !my_app.config or using @private in the docstring? https://pdoc.dev/docs/pdoc.html#control-what-is-documented

@r_2009: I considered it but as far as I understand it hides the variable entirely. But as I mentioned I want SETTINGS to be documented but it does not make much sense to document its value as the value depends on the environment and may contain confidential infos.

Fair point; there's a suggestion in the github issue to use pdoc as a library and customize the documentation build process: https://github.com/mitmproxy/pdoc/issues/621

One solution proposed on GitHub [1] is to use a custom jinja template:
{% extends "default/module.html.jinja2" %}
{# ./templates/module.html.jinja2 #}

{% macro default_value(var) %}
    {% if var.modulename != "mypackage.config" %}
        {{ default_default_value(var) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

and generate documentation with pdoc -t ./templates mypackage. I guess I will check whether I can combine this with a pre-commit hook just in case someone accidentally calls pdoc directly without the template parameter.
Edit: Unfortunately, values hidden with a jinja template will still be included in the search.js search index. I opened an issue at mitmproxy/pdoc.
